# Programatically installing or removing a Firefox add-on, without the notice box

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-addon

**Not as evil as it sounds!**

This is for a corporate deployment tool.  One of the things they want to do is to manage browser add-ons & plugins.  UI wise, the client considers it inappropriate for a dialog to pop-up.

What I need to do is copy out xpi files to the destination systems, but how do I trigger an install.

install-global-extensions polls the user to ask permission for the install.

obviously windows, in a very uncool move, install FF add-ons without polling the user.  So it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use the windows registry to install an add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry).